# What is causing this cartthrob orders edit date formatting issue

Tags: cartthrob, entry-date, orders, edit-date

Version Info: EE 3.4.5 Cartthrob Pro 3.0.2

While looking at my admin CP today, I noticed that all cartthrob placed orders have some really strange edit dates. While the exact cause is unknown to me, I can clearly see that the problem is being caused by how the edit date is being added to the DB.

For example, for a newly created order, the entry date in the DB is a standard 10 digit Unix timestamp. i.e., 1487232589.
However, the edit date is added to the DB as YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. i.e., 20170216171049

Please note that this happens for all new entries.  Upon actually opening and editing an entry via the CP, the edit date is corrected to a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have spoken with Vector media about this issue and it has been determined to be a bug that resulted due to changes in the date functions from EE2 to EE3. This issue should be addressed in future releases of Cartthrob.

The actual cause of the difference in dates is below:

/cartthrob/models/cartthrob_entries_model.php has a public function (starting LINE 212) for create_entry.

LINE 235 and LINE 236 are the date fields.
entry_date is localized time but edit_date is (YmdHis).